# Why would pip install python packages outside of my current virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pip, django-nonrel

I just installed virtualenv earlier today, and I've been trying to get django-nonrel to work using a virtual environment. After many hours of trying and failing to do so, I chatted with someone who suggested that the problem is with pip itself.

I create a virtual environment with `virtualenv env_name`. I enter it with:

```
source env_name/bin/activate
```

I then install something with pip. For example,

```
sudo pip install git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel;
```

I then perform a `pip freeze`, and the only output is:

```
wsgiref=0.1.2
```

Can anyone see why this might happen?

Thanks,

ParagonRG

Notes:

- pip is version 1.1.
- virtualenv is version 1..7.1.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the git extension

```
$> mkvirtualenv test
(test)> pip install  git+https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-nonrel.git 
(test)> pip freeze
Django==1.3.1
wsgiref==0.1.2
```

By the way, you dont need to use `sudo` if you work with virtualenv. The idea is having your virtualen somewhere you have permission like ~/.virtualenvs/

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Thank you, kind sirs. This problem has been bugging me for hours! I'm having a bad day of development.